# Functions: Shift items in different directions within list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

**I need to return a Boolean** if moving values across the list is possible. '.' are empty spots where strings could move to. For the 1st func, how would I shift both identical values left and right? I'm not sure how to define the left and right variables and was wondering if I need the pop.() to delete the spot I'm moving the variables to.

```
area1 = [['.', '.', '.', 'e'], 
         ['A', 'A', '.', 'e'], 
         ['.', 'X', '.', 'e'], 
         ['.', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'], 
         ['.', '.', 'Z', 'Z']]

def shift_horizontal(value, direction, area):
    for i in range(len(area)-1):
        for j in range(len(row)-1):
            if right and value[i] == '.'[i+1]: # Will shift right if value next is '.'
                return True
            elif left and value[i] == '.'[i-1]: # Will shift left if value next is '.'
                return True
            else:
                return False
shift_horizontal('A', right, area1)
```

How the list should look like after(I don't actually need to return the list, just a visual reference):

```
area1 = [['.', '.', '.', 'e'], 
         ['.', 'A', 'A', 'e'], 
         ['.', 'X', '.', 'e'], 
         ['.', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'], 
         ['.', '.', 'Z', 'Z']]
```

I plan to write a 2nd function which will only moves values up and down the list. What would I need to change in the function above to make it only move like variables up and down within the list? Any help/advice appreciated. I'm trying to keep it simple with only loops and Booleans with few built in functions as tedious as it sounds.

Answer (score 1):

```
def shift_horizontal(value, direction, area):#direction True is left
    result = []
    for lane in area:
        if not direction:
            lane = reversed(lane)
        try:
            ind = lane.index(value)
            result.append( '.' in lane[:index])
        except ValueError:
            result.append(False)
    return result
```

Returns a list of booleans.  Flip the list, depending on direction.  Then find the leftmost index of `value`.  Then check the list up to that point for `'.'`.  Not sure if this is exactly what you want.  If you want to see if there is an adjacent `'.'` then do `if lane[index-1] == '.'` instead

Comment: Close to what I need, but is there a way to do away with the ValueError and try functions? I was mentioned a while loop it over to get the length of string 'A' and modify the list to get the resulting list.

Comment: If they're guaranteed to be characters, you can do `ind = (''.join(lane)).find(value)` this returns the index, or -1 if it's not in the list

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use -1 & +1 instead of Left and Right.
To move all 'A's in a single run:
If the direction is +1 (to right), iterate over the inner list from right to left, try to move every 'A' as you encounter, until the end of that row.
If the direction is -1 (to left), iterate from left to right instead.

```
area1 = [['.', '.', '.', 'e'], 
         ['A', 'A', '.', 'e'], 
         ['.', 'X', '.', 'e'], 
         ['.', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'], 
         ['.', '.', 'Z', 'Z']]

def move_horizontal(table, value, direction):
    is_anything_moved = False
    for row in table:
        width = len(row)
        # Traverse the row (skipping the first element) from right to left if direction is 1. 
        for x in (range(1,width,1) if direction==-1 else range(width-2,-1,-1)): 
            if row[x]==value: #found a value match, now move it as far as we can
                i = x+direction # new index of value
                while i<width and i>=0 and row[i]=='.':
                    row[i-direction] = '.'
                    row[i] = value
                    i += direction
                    is_anything_moved = True
    return is_anything_moved

[print(row) for row in area1]
print()

move_horizontal(area1,'A',1)

[print(row) for row in area1]
print()

move_horizontal(area1,'e',-1)

[print(row) for row in area1]
```

This should output :

```
['.', '.', '.', 'e']
['A', 'A', '.', 'e']
['.', 'X', '.', 'e']
['.', 'X', 'Y', 'Y']
['.', '.', 'Z', 'Z']

['.', '.', '.', 'e']
['.', 'A', 'A', 'e']
['.', 'X', '.', 'e']
['.', 'X', 'Y', 'Y']
['.', '.', 'Z', 'Z']

['e', '.', '.', '.']
['.', 'A', 'A', 'e']
['.', 'X', 'e', '.']
['.', 'X', 'Y', 'Y']
['.', '.', 'Z', 'Z']
```